# Error saying "itk" not installed, but it is installed

Tags: centos7, itk

I am trying to install the ab-initio program quantum-espresso (v. 7) on my centos 7.9 system.  The different sub-programs compile and link without error. While the main programs work fine (command line/file based), the gui (PWgui) raises an error when it run stating that "itk" (object-oriented extensions to Tk) is not installed. It is, however installed (take a look at the clipping below for reference).  Any suggestions as to how to resolve this?

```
(base) > /data/Software/qe-7.0/GUI/PWgui>./pwgui

 ==================================================
  This is PWgui version: 7.0
 --------------------------------------------------


 PWgui: using the system default "tclsh" interpreter

 PWGUI       : /data/Software/qe-7.0/GUI/PWgui
 GUIB engine : /data/Software/qe-7.0/GUI/PWgui/lib/Guib-0.6

can't find package itk
    while executing
"package require itk"
    (file "/data/Software/qe-7.0/GUI/PWgui/lib/Guib-0.6/init.tcl" line 12)
    invoked from within
"source /data/Software/qe-7.0/GUI/PWgui/lib/Guib-0.6/init.tcl"
    ("package ifneeded Guib 0.6" script)
    invoked from within
"package require Guib 0.5"
    (file "/data/Software/qe-7.0/GUI/PWgui/init.tcl" line 5)
    invoked from within
"source [file join $env(PWGUI) init.tcl]"
    (file "/data/Software/qe-7.0/GUI/PWgui/pwgui.tcl" line 60)
(base) > su
Password: 
(base) > :/data/Software/qe-7.0/GUI/PWgui>yum install itk-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.iij.ad.jp
 * centos-sclo-rh: ftp.iij.ad.jp
 * centos-sclo-sclo: ftp.iij.ad.jp
 * epel: ftp.iij.ad.jp
 * extras: ftp.iij.ad.jp
 * updates: ftp.iij.ad.jp
Package itk-devel-3.4-9.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 0):

Current stable version of ITK is [5.2.1](https://itk.org/download/). ITK [3.4](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/releases/tag/v3.4.0) is 15 years old. I think Tk could access ITK in some old versions. But this smells like versions problem.

Comment: I agree it seems to be an old version, but this is the latest version in epel. How to go about installing a more recent version? Is there a rpm or must it be compiled from scratch?

Comment: I installed the latest version of itk via conda-forge (as stated on the itk.org page), but I still see the same error message. Any ideas of how to troubleshoot this?